# Pipe Broken, FIFO file

Tags: c++, c

I'm trying a program to use FIFO file, but I'm getting Broken pipe as output. Here is the code -

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/stat.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
int fd; //stores file descriptor returnd from open
char buf[256];
if(argc<2||argc>3)
{
    cout<<"Invalid Arguments";
    return 1;
}

mkfifo(argv[1],0777);
if(argc==3)
{   
    cout<<"Writer\n";
    if((fd=open(argv[1],O_WRONLY))==-1)
    {
        perror("open");
        return 1;
    }
    write(fd,argv[2],strlen(argv[2]));
    sleep(10);
}
else
{   cout<<"Reader\n";
    if((fd=open(argv[1],O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK))==-1)
    {       
        perror("open");
        return 1;
    }

    read(fd,&buf,sizeof(buf));
    cout<<buf;

}
 close(fd);
 return 1;
 }
```

Output: 
Below Fifo is the name of the file and Hello is the content.

> ```
> ./a.out fifo hello &
>
> Writer
>
> ./a.out fifo
> Reader
>
> [1]+  Broken pipe
> ```

I should get "Hello" as the output. Can anyone help?

Comment: You should really check for error from *all* system calls.

Comment: Ya sorry, edited. Didn't effect the output though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your write happens before you start your reader. When you write to a pipe and it has no reader you get SIGPIPE.

In this particular design, you need to *handle* SIGPIPE with retry logic.

Comment: How do I make the reader to read the pipe as soon as writer starts writing? thanks for the reply

Comment: It's the other way around. The reader needs to be reading before the writer starts writing. The reader will repeatedly get EOF until the writer is attached to the pipe.

Answer (score 1):

The error you get is `EPIPE` and if you read a [`write`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html) manual you will see that you get `EPIPE` when

> `fd` is connected to a pipe or socket whose reading end is closed.

You get this error because you open the reading end of the pipe in non-blocking mode, which means the `read` call will not block and wait for data to be received, instead when the `read` call immediately return you close the pipe and exit the process.

That means when you run the writer there is no one waiting for the data you write and you get the error.

You need to run the read and the writer in opposite order: First the writer so it writes to the pipe, and *then* the reader to read the data from the pipe.